# Autocomplete in JQuery getting uncaught type error

Tags: jquery

While executing below code then getting below exception. I am new in this section so unable to understand why its throwing this exception.

```
$("#city").bind("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

> ERROR :: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of undefined

Comment: What is `$(this).data("autocomplete")` meant to be? Is it a plugin that hasn't been initialised yet? You should check it exists before accessing properties on it

Answer (score 0):

maybe error in link :
[jquery cdn](http://%3Cscript%20%20%20src=%22https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js%22%20%20%20integrity=%22sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=%22%20%20%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```